# What other medical options are there in Star Wars

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

As this quote shows, it seems that *[bacta](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bacta)* use has pushed other medical treatments out as obsolete:

> "Everyone uses Bacta. We've been using it so long, it's replaced most conventional medicine."

Did other medical treatments exist? How advanced were they? (No need for a list, just some general information please).

---

### Edit:

Whilst alternatives to bacta are nice, I was hopping if someone could say if other *procedures* as well as medicines existed, like anti-biotics, surgery, blood transfusion or if they had been replaced by bacta.

Comment: Well, we do know they can't regrow limbs severed off with lightsabers.

Comment: @pureferret - they do **exist**, likely, but aren't usually shown. The only example I can think of was Han Solo tilogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [MedStar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/MedStar_I%3a_Battle_Surgeons) books, they do have surgeons. Those books were very much like MASH. They had descriptions on some of the procedures they used. The part I remember was there were force fields around their patients to prevent infections.

Answer (score 4):

There are still mechanical protheses for cut off limbs and other parts (see Luke and Vader's hands) where Bacta can't regrow them, and there are known rare cases of allergies against Bacta, so there are as well cybernetic replacements for internal organs (see [Tom Phanan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ton_Phanan)).

There is as well [Ryll kor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ryll_kor), a spice from Ryloth with some healing faculties which was used in [X-wing: The Krytos Trap](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/X-wing%3a_The_Krytos_Trap) to enhance the Bacta treatments.

Answer (score 4):

Previously, Bacta shared the market with [Kolto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolto).

When Kolto supplies collapsed, Bacta became fully widely used.

Bacta was synthetic, but mostly produced on 1 planet. Kolto was an organic compound, thought to be a byproduct of a Progenitor being on planet Manaan.